# Import scip to python

Tags: python, osx-yosemite, scip

I've tried unsuccessfully to get scip running with python. I'm using Yosemite (10.10.3), python 2.7 and have installed scip optimization suit (http://scip.zib.de/download.php?fname=scipoptsuite-3.1.1.tgz) with make.

I can start scip after the installation via the terminal.

```
sages-MBP:~ sage$ scip SCIP version 3.1.1 [precision: 8 byte] [memory: block] >[mode:optimized][LP solver: SoPlex 2.0.1] [GitHash: bade511]
```

But when I try to use `import scip` in python there appears the message

```
No module named scip
```

The same error message appears for `from zibopt import scip`

If I print the system path with `print sys.path` in python, the folder `scipoptsuite-3.1.1/scip-3.1.1/bin` is included where the file
`scip-3.1.1.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt.spx` is situated. 
Is it possible that the reason for the error message is that I haven't linked correctly necessary libraries?

Or which folders have to be included in the pythonpath to get scip working?

I Hope someone can help me out!

Comment: The file `scip-3.1.1.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt.spx` isn't what you need, it's going to be named either `scip.py` or `scip.so` (or possibly `scip-stuff-other-stuff.so`, but usually not for 2.x). Whatever directory has _that_ file is the one that has to be on your `sys.path`.

Comment: (Unless `scip` actually installs a special module loader for `.spx` files, but I doubt it does.)

Comment: The actual `scip.py` folder has to be either in the `sys.path` or inside the directory where your python file is located. Even if `scip.py` was blank, you wouldn't get the error, indicating the module is not in either of the places it should be.

Comment: Try changing into the directory where you unpacked the SCIP tarball, and installing the headers, libraries, and binary. Not sure if you did that step.

Comment: I've done `make` and `sudo make install INSTALLDIR="/usr/local/` in 'scip-3.1.1', but I couldn't find a file `scip.py` or `scip-stuff-other-stuff.so` in the '/usr/local/' or its subfolders either.

Comment: Could you please add the information which of the two available python interfaces for SCIP you are trying to use? There is the [python-zibopt-interface](https://code.google.com/p/python-zibopt/wiki/Installation) that, as far as I know, only runs with SCIP Opt Suite 2.1, and the more recent interface included in scip in the answer by @mattmilten below.

Comment: I tried to get the test file from [python-zibopt-interface] running but for the package I've downloaded [http://scip.zib.de/download.php?fname=scipoptsuite-3.1.1.tgz] I probably have to use the interface that was proposed by @mattmilten

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the python interface that comes with SCIP. Go to `scip/interfaces/python/` and read the instructions in `README` and `INSTALL`. This interface is using [Cython](http://cython.org/) to communicate with the C-Code of SCIP.

`make` will only install the native Linux or Mac binaries/libraries.

The environment variable `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` needs to be set to contain the `lib/` directory of the SCIPoptSuite installation (see comment by @саша)

Comment: I followed the `INSTALL` instructions. But I get now an library error:  `E   ImportError: dlopen(/System/Library/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyscipopt/scip.so, 2): Library not loaded: lib/libscipopt-3.1.1.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt.so
E     Referenced from: /System/Library/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyscipopt/scip.so
E     Reason: image not found`   I've used `python setup.py install` and specified the paths when prompted during the installation: `/scip-opt-path/scipoptsuite-3.1.1/lib/libscipopt-3.1.1.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt.so` `/scip-opt-path/scipoptsuite-3.1.1/scip-3.1.1/src`

Comment: You may need to update your ```PYTHON_PATH``` to point to ```pyscipopt/scip.so```. I have never seen the error code ```image not found```, though, so I'm not sure how to fix this.

Comment: Updating the `PYTHON_PATH` hasn't helped. But after adding `export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path-to-scip-opt/scipoptsuite-3.1.1/lib/` to my bash I can import scip to python. I know that `export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` is not the recommended procedure, but it is working.

Comment: Good to hear that it works now! I have never heard of ```DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH``` before - seems to be exclusive for Mac OS.

Please tell me if you find a cleaner solution. We will put it into our next release.